# Pandas : creating multi-level table or sub table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, multi-level

I have data in dictionary format in a list as :

```
data_dict = [{
    "exchange": "binance",
    "base": "kp3r",
    "quote": "busd",
    "resolution": 15,
    "ohlcv": [
        {
            "source_id": 7905,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z",
            "open": "131.55",
            "high": "131.84",
            "low": "130.38",
            "close": "130.94",
            "volume": "90.29"
        },
        {
            "source_id": 7905,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z",
            "open": "131.55",
            "high": "131.84",
            "low": "130.38",
            "close": "130.94",
            "volume": "90.29"
        },
        {
            "source_id": 19252,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z",
            "open": "24.5610000000000000",
            "high": "24.5610000000000000",
            "low": "24.5610000000000000",
            "close": "24.5610000000000000",
            "volume": "0.0000000000000000"
        }]
    },
    {
    "exchange": "kucoin",
    "base": "mln",
    "quote": "usdt",
    "resolution": 15,
    "ohlcv": [
        {
            "source_id": 19252,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z",
            "open": "24.56",
            "high": "24.56",
            "low": "24.56",
            "close": "24.56",
            "volume": "0.0"
        }]
    }
]
```

Now I need the table to be something like (**Expected**) :

```
      exchange  base  ... resolution   source_id      timestamp             open    high   low    close  volume
    0  binance  kp3r  ...         15     7905     2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z  131.55 131.84  130.38 130.94  90.29
                                         7905     2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z  131.55 131.84  130.38 130.94  90.29
                                         19252    2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z  24.56   24.56  24.56   24.56   0.0

    1   kucoin   mln  ...         15     19252    2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z  24.56   24.56  24.56   24.56   0.0
```

This is what I have tried :

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```

which gives me

```
  exchange  base  ... resolution                                              ohlcv
0  binance  kp3r  ...         15  [{'source_id': 7905, 'timestamp': '2022-07-05T...
1   kucoin   mln  ...         15  [{'source_id': 19252, 'timestamp': '2022-07-05...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).explode("ohlcv")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("ohlcv").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  exchange  base quote  resolution  source_id                 timestamp    open    high     low   close volume
0  binance  kp3r  busd          15       7905  2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z  131.55  131.84  130.38  130.94  90.29
0  binance  kp3r  busd          15       7905  2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z  131.55  131.84  130.38  130.94  90.29
1   kucoin   mln  usdt          15      19252  2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z   24.56   24.56   24.56   24.56    0.0
```

Comment: Is it not possible for those columns to be empty? like I showed without us setting them empty

Comment: if not, can we do the same using multi index

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Can you update your question and put there expected output?

Comment: I have the expected output in question please check `Now I need the table to be something like (Expected) :`